# Scale out Windows container in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, windows-container

We are running our application using Azure App Service. It is based in .NET FW 4.7 with Webforms and API Rest. We are using PC3 App Service Plan (16GB RAM). The application is stateless and it supports the Application Service scale out without a problem.

In a first step to modernize our infrastructure, the application was packaged in a Windows Container and it is executed in an App Service. The image is based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8` and uploaded to ACR. The problem occurs when trying to scale out the application. At the time of scale-out, the new container is added to the balancer and some requests are answered with "The Web App's container is starting up!"

Is there a way to add the new container to the balancer only when it is fully functional?

Note: I don't know if this is related to the problem but it appears in the log:

> CONTAINER_HEALTH_CHECK_MODE app setting is set to ReportOnly. Container will not be recycled. For container to be recycled when it becomes unhealthy set it to Repair

Comment: How large is that container? Is the image located in ACR? In the same Azure data centre?

Comment: The image is based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8` and uploaded to ACR. We are using the same Azure data center. The docker image is quite large. Only our application adds 400 megabytes. The creation of an App Service (PC2) with this image can take 25 minutes to be fully functional.